# Defining a changing variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a variable that will link to others based off of a variable result, but can't seem to get it to work. Here's the code:

```
@echo off
set rollnumbera=10
set /a num=%random% %%rollnumbera +1
set "message=msg%num%"
set msg1=a
set msg2=b
set msg3=c
set msg4=d
set msg5=e
set msg6=f
set msg7=g
set msg8=h
set msg9=i
set msg10=j
echo %message%
echo %num%
pause
```

When I run it it displays the `msg%num%` result, but does not seem to be linking to the set msg#s. I'm wondering if there is a way to do that, or if an `"if %num% == message number (echo message)"` is required. This is just an ease of access question, but any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @Compo, what would that change??

Comment: I think you are looking for this: `call set "message=%%msg%num%%%"`, but this has to be moved below the message definitions; **or** you write `call echo %%%message%%%`...

Comment: "Changing variable" **=** "array element"  **->**  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fixed code:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set rollnumbera=10 
set /a num=(%random% %% rollnumbera)+1 
set msg1=a 
set msg2=b 
set msg3=c 
set msg4=d 
set msg5=e 
set msg6=f 
set msg7=g 
set msg8=h 
set msg9=i 
set msg10=j 
for %%a in ("!msg%num%!") do set message=%%a
echo %message% 
echo %num% 
pause
```